# How do you solve $\frac{x-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fractions

I've been having a bit of trouble understanding the formula

$$\frac{x-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1}$$

Apparently it equals sqrt(x) but I have no clue how to get that.  Whenever I multiply it out I get

$$\frac{(x-\sqrt x)(\sqrt x+1)}{x-1}$$

How do I simplify it further?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The second fraction is $1$ and the first fraction is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{x}}(\sqrt{x}-1)}{(\sqrt{x}-1)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @Kal Welcome to Math SE! Here's a guide to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: That's definitely it.  I didn't even think to take out a factor of sqrt(x) instead of multiplying by the conjugate.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that $(x-\sqrt x)(\sqrt x + 1)=x\sqrt x-\sqrt x$ by just expanding the parentheses. Maybe now it's a little clearer that you can take out a factor $\sqrt x$?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Could you please convert your comment into an answer so this question doesn't sit in the "Unanswered" queue for ages?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of this question not remaining in the unanswered queue ...

The second fraction is 1 and the first fraction is
\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{x}}(\sqrt{x}-1)}{(\sqrt{x}-1)}. \end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1}$

$\frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1}$ go to 1.

So, $\frac{x-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x-1} \cdot\ 1 = \frac{x-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x-1} $

We can say that:

$\frac{x-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x-1}$ = $\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}$

which is basically:

$\frac{\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)}$

Cancel the like terms and you will end up with
$\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical high school problem when teaching rationalizing a denominator.  A method which actually demonstrates the concept.

$$\frac{(x- \sqrt x)(\sqrt x +1)}{(\sqrt x -1)(\sqrt x +1)}=$$

The top F.O.I.L.'s out or multiplies as follows.  Note how x applies to each term in the right parentheses resulting in the first two terms.  Then -root x applies to each term in the right parentheses resulting in the 3rd and 4th terms.

$$\frac{x\sqrt x +x -\sqrt x \sqrt x -\sqrt x}{(\sqrt x -1)(\sqrt x +1)}$$

Note that when $$-\sqrt x \sqrt x$$ simplifies, it becomes -x.  So x - x cancels leaving
$$\frac{x*\sqrt x -\sqrt x}{(\sqrt x -1)(\sqrt x +1)}$$

The top factors and the questioner seems to understand the bottom becomes x -1

$$\frac{\sqrt x (x -1)}{ x- 1}$$

Also, for education purposes, this method applies to a more common and broader range of exercises than factoring square root of x.